Trying to understand "Shtukas"
I'm studying Goss' Basic structures of function field Arithmetic, chapter 6 about Shtukas. I'm trying to understand some details about some concepts. This chapter is based on a Mumford's paper An algebro-geometric construction of commuting operators and of solutions to the Toda lattice equation. Specifically, let be $X$ a reduced and irreducible complete curve over a field $L_0$ and set $\bar{X}= L \otimes X$, where $L$ is an extension of $L_0$.  Mumford considers a torsion-free coherent $O_\bar{X}$-module $F$ on $\bar{X}$ and a maximal flag of coherent sub $O_\bar{X}$-modules $F_n$
\begin{gather*}
F=F_0 \supset F_{-1} \supset \dotsb \supset F_{-t}=F(-P),
\end{gather*}
where $P=L \otimes P_0$, $P_0$ a regular closed point of $X$.
Then, both Mumford and Goss define $F_n$ for all $n$ by requiring
\begin{gather*}
F_{j+t}= F_j(P).
\end{gather*}
After that, both mention that, from general properties of coherent cohomology one sees that $\chi (F_n) = n$ and $h^0(F_n) \leq h^0(F_{n+1})$ and $h^1(F_n) \geq h^1(F_{n+1})$. Why $\chi(F_n)=n$ and the inequalities hold?
I'm a very novice at this theme, so if anyone of you knows where I can study more of this topic (and preliminaries), it would be very helpful!

You may want to include some details about what $F_n$ looks like, in order to make this more self contained.

I added more information. Thanks for you advice.

Is $F$ assumed to have Euler characteristic zero?  Otherwise this all seems wrong.  There should be an exact sequence $0\to F_n \to F_{n+1} \to O_P \to 0$, and taking the long exact sequence in cohomology will show that the Euler characteristic goes up by 1 when n does and we have the inequalities on cohomology.

@JackHuizenga Thanks for your response. Neither Mumford nor Goss mencioned $\chi (F)=0$. However, the flag have $length (F_{n+1}/F_n)=1$.

On page 184, Proposition 6.2.3 the hypothesis that $\chi(F)=0$ is explicitly established. The proposition concludes that $h^0(F)=h^1(F)=0$.

@MChocko, Mumford https://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/alg_geom/papers/1978a--CommOps-TodaKdV-NC.pdf on its several Data A and Data B bijections, starting on page 116 also has the hypothesis that $\chi(F)=0$.

@FZaldivar You´re right, my fault. Thanks to everyone! Is there a book in order to learn coherent cohomology? As a novice, I´m lost in this topic.

Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry and may other similar books discuss coherent cohomology.

@JackHuizenga, excuse me, How can I calculate $\chi(O_p)$?. I've tried to use the additivity of $\chi$. For example, if I have $0 \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow O_P$, then $\chi(F_1)=\chi(O_P)$ I would like to say that $\chi(O_P)=1$, but, how?

It's 1, compute its cohomology.

Really, thanks for helping me!
